# Visual Studio 2010 IntelliSense doesn't select a default value - it just marks it

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, coderush-xpress, visual-studio-2010

I have a pretty annoying problem with the IntelliSense in Visual Studio 2010:

Every now and then (but not always - just out of my control) the Intellisense engine chooses to "mark" an option, instead of actually selecting it. This means that instead of typing <kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> to access the default option starting with "En...", I have to type <kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> <kbd>**down**</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Usually it works like this for a while, and then, suddenly, the behavior I want is back. My conclusion is that there is some option somewhere that is set automatically, and that I don't know how to control.

How do I make sure that the default option is always selected, and not just "marked"?

For reference: This is Visual Studio 2010 RC, with CodeRush Xpress 10.1.

Comment: @devio: did you ever find out why?

Answer (score 280, accepted):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>.

found that [on Connect](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpide/thread/5ae00716-d9e5-4667-ae16-80f69e7c9556), and seems to work for me

Comment: Microsoft articles tend to disappear after a while. It would be nice to explain a little why and how

Answer (score 81):

It can also be changed by going to Edit -> IntelliSense -> ToggleCompletionMode

Comment: plus one for finding an alternative way for those who may have changed their shortcuts.

Comment: Thank you. I might have ignored Ctrl+Alt+Space thinking it could never be a permanent fix, but that it would only affect what you're currently typing. Even though it turns out to be the same thing as this, this caught my eye and helps me understand what I'm doing.

Comment: vs2017, still works. And it still turns itself off randomly... this bug has been here a long damn time.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell I won't write off the possibility that I fat fingered Ctr+Alt+Space instead of it changing randomly.

Comment: Works with vs2019 which I thought was broken at some point. Thanks, you saved my nerves every time i write a C# property!

Comment: @DouglasGaskell apparently still there and turns itself off randomly. Any updates on this?

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem, but find pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> always selects the default selection.

Comment: True. But you still have to press period to bring up the member's list. One extra step :(

Comment: @Tomas. Of course you do - all of the solutions above rely on that. Imagine if that didn't happen. You  start typing the name of a variable, which in the first few letters could match several variables with similar names but different types, and ALL the members for all those types popped up automatically. Pressing a period key may be an extra step but it saves your sanity!

Answer (score 9):

For completeness, this option has a toggle button up on the toolbar:

[image: Toggle Completion Mode toolbar button]

Its visual status will tell you which completion mode is currently selected.

Comment: While probably true, and valuable info today, I'm a little impressed that you found this >10-year-old question to write this :)

Comment: It's top of the "related" list for similar questions, and pops up quite nicely on search. It's still relevant despite being a decade old!

Comment: WTH! Simple and straightforward. Thanks. VS2019.

Answer (score 4):

For C++ at least,

```
Tools / Options / Text Editor / C/C++/ Advanced / IntelliSense
```

and change `Member List Commit Aggressive` to `True`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was going mad because I couldn't find this option! Maybe they can rename this option, because it is a bit hidden with its current name. Or at least make it active by default...

Answer (score 2):

You might switched into low- impact IntelliSense mode, just hit Ctrl+Alt+Space and it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should just do it :
Edit / IntelliSense / Toggle Completion Mode

[I can Solve it with this Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rnm9S.png)