# Visual Studio 2010 IntelliSense -> Enter will not AutoComplete any more

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I am very much use IntelliSence of VS2010.
Sometimes, I can not tell when and why, the IntelliSence changes.

Example: Label lblTestTest

The normal behavoir is:
I type "lblTes" - see the IntelliSence who select the Label - Push Enter - Autocomplete the word, I type ".Te" - see the IntelliSence who select the Property ".Text" - Push Enter - Autocomplete.

Sometimes it is:
I type "lblTes" - see the IntelliSence who select the Label - Push Enter - *The Enter does NOT activate the AutoComplete, It makes an Enter (LineBreak) in my Code, WITHOUT autocomplete*.

I have to: 
I type "lblTes" - see the IntelliSence who select the Label - Push down - Push Enter  - Autocomplete

I hopw you guys understand what I mean. Its only a little difference, but it steals me hours in total, when this "bug" or "Change" is there.

Any Idea?

Comment: I never use Enter, I use Tab.  Disable add-ins, uninstall Bing toolbar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2010 IntelliSense doesn't select a default value - it just marks it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639481/visual-studio-2010-intellisense-doesnt-select-a-default-value-it-just-marks-i)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I had same problem, but I found a fix.

In VS 2010 there is new suggestion mode, what is good, sometimes, but most of times it's not. So when autocomplete box is shown, press crtl+alt+space to go to old mode. And if you need go back to suggestion mode, press crtl+alt+space again.

Comment: Thanks for that llkka. That thing i VS2010 has annoyed me a lot. Now that problem is a goner =)

Comment: Aaaahhh Thats better. Its amazing how annoying this stupid problem is. Must have accidentally hit ctrl+alt+space somewhere along the way.

Answer (score 6):

In VS2017, for C++ at least, go to

```
Tools/Options/Text Editor/C/C++/Advanced/IntelliSense
```

and change 
`Member List Commit Aggressive` to `True`

Also you can use <kbd>TAB</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>.