# How to change tab with enter key for autocomplete?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Using VS2017 in C++ app. I found the intellisense only outline the word and I have to press on `tab` key for autocomplete while pressing on `Enter` does not autocomplete the word and start a new line so is there an option to use `Enter` instead of `Tab` ?

Comment: I am not sure this counts as an answer but I believe it is a quirk of VS that `Tab` is the most aggressive autocomplete input. Enter, I believe, does work once intellisense figures out what you are typing but I think it struggles since there are many more valid uses for `Enter` than `Tab`. But the C++ intellisense can be slow so it may never figure it out especially as the volume of potential matches increases and the macros really mess with how easily intellisense can deal with `Enter` or anything not `Tab` since it needs to figure out a lot more context than say C#.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883898/visual-studio-2010-intellisense-enter-will-not-autocomplete-any-more
Bogdan's answer works for me

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- ***Goto*** => Tools >> Options >> Text Editor >> C/C++ >> Advanced >> IntelliSense
- ***Change*** => Member List Commit Aggressive to True

Comment: Unfortunately it still does not work for me.. Using VS 2019 Community, on a C++ project; there is also no option to toggle "Completion mode" :(

Comment: Worked in VS 2022 Community for me.

Comment: Worked with me too in VS 2022 Community but I prefer Rider so I switched

Answer (score 2):

This function worked for me in visual 2019

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you can use VSC, it autocompletes on `Enter` in addition to `Tab` by default. If you'd like to change that so `Enter` starts a new line, go to `(File > Preferences >) Settings > Text Editor > Suggestions > Accept Suggestions On Enter > Select on, off or smart.` ("Controls whether suggestions should be accepted on Enter, in addition to Tab [...]").

Answer (score 0):

Most of what I read online didn't work for me, majorly my menus weren't as suggested. What I could do to make it work was: Tools > Options > Text Editor > Basic (I'm using VB.net) > Intellisense (many had this under Advanced, for me they are 2 separated fields) > Enter key behavior (it's a radiobutton selection) > Only add new line on enter after end if fully typed word