# Stop moving the line down after clicking the cout from IntelliSense

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am new to Visual Studio and C++. The problem is this: when I type the cout keyword and press Enter on the word in the IntelliSense tab, the line in the text editor moves down. I want to disable it. Where to look in options to solve this problem?

Comment: For autocomplete, click **tab** instead. The return key goes down a line and that's it works

Comment: This works fine, thanks. But I am not used to press the tab key so often. Is there any way to change to "Enter" keyword?

Comment: I am not sure. See if this works [How to change tab with enter key for autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50540093/10147399)

Comment: Hmm ... how odd ... enter works for me. :-) I don't remember having set that up somehow. I'm using VS2019

Comment: You could set `True` in `Tools->Options->Text Editor->C/C++->Advanced->IntelliSense->Member List Commit Aggressive`. If it does not work, you could try `Ctrl+Alt+Space` to open `suggestion mode`.