# How to rebind autocompletion acceptance in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a very serious problem when I type my code in visual studio the only way I have to discard the autocompletion suggestion is to press `space`.

For instance I want to type `index,` and it replace everything with `IndexError,` I would like it to accept autocomplete suggestion only if I press `tab` and not every single special caracter. I have this problem if I type `= , ; (` etc instead of `space` and this is EXTREMLY annoying, I mean it is not mandatory to have a space between all your items so how can one do such thing ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here, but is it related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639481/visual-studio-2010-intellisense-doesnt-select-a-default-value-it-just-marks-i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all configurable in the settings: Tools → Options → Text Editor → Text Editor → C# → IntelliSense

Focus on these two options:

1. **Committed by typing the following characters** — This specifies a list of characters that should select the highlighted item in the IntelliSense drop-down list.
2. **Committed by pressing the space bar** — This specifies whether the space bar should be included in the above list of characters that select the highlighted item.

This is all covered by [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcf2zk43.aspx).

I can't tell you exactly how you should set these though, because your question doesn't otherwise make a lot of sense. First you say that you want the comma to select the current IntelliSense suggestion, then you say that you "would like it to accept autocomplete suggestion only if I press Tab". Seems contradictory. Either way, play with the options until you get the behavior you want.

Comment: I'm not saying I want comma to select the current suggestion I'm just stating the fact that it does indeed select the current selection and that it's a pain in the ass. Anyway I'm going to check what you say.

Comment: well this doesn't work. Maybe it's just supposed to work for C# files but I'm coding in Python, I can't find the related intellisense options for python and I still got the problem.

Comment: Hmm yeah, I assumed you were using a language supported by Visual Studio. C# is a common one, but there are similar options for other supported languages. No idea about Python.

Comment: oh well got it, it wasn't under `intellisense` but `advanced`